# How to update wireshark interface list?

Tags: 14.04, wireshark

I installed Wireshark(v1.10.6) from software centre. In the interface list, only bluetooth is shown. I wanted to capture packets that are sent & received from wireless connection.

How should I do it? Is there any way to add wireless and wired connections into this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can't capture network interfaces as normal user, you need administrative rights to access the network layer.
You can try running wireshark as "root" and check if the interfaces are shown.

P.S.: You should use the root account only for testing purpose. Pay attention to the messagebox that will show up when you run wireshark as root.

Answer (score 3):

Try quitting Wireshark, doing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

from the command line, and restarting Wireshark.  That should give you permission to access "normal" network adapters *without* having to run Wireshark as root, which, as sinclair notes, you really don't want to do - to quote the doc/README.packaging file in the Wireshark source:

```
WIRESHARK CONTAINS OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE. DO NOT RUN
THEM AS ROOT.
```